# Useful design patterns when dealing with spring 3 controllers

Tags: spring, design-patterns, controller

Recently I was overlooking my controllers and they are bit of mess.

- I'd like to organize they way I set returning views
- Do more elegant mesageSource massaging back to the users and account for i18n
- Security checking, what user can access an what they can't
- Consistent way of calling the service layer
- And somehow bring consistency to the debugging lines.
- Do better job with error handling and serving it to the user.

I'm already on mission to do security logging with AOP :)

I'm just looking for patterns I could implement to help me to do all of the above.
Or just some general advice in case no patterns apply, or advice on something I didn't mention but is common practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - I'd like to organize they way I set returning views

When you build a web application with mostly CRUD operations, then you should have a look at the REST style / pattern. This helps to organize your controllers and views.